# React Running Successfully on Local Machine but failing on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, vercel

So I am attempting to launch my site to Vercel but am getting a "failed to compile" error, even though the build logs also show that the build was successfully compiled:

```
[16:43:24.951] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[16:43:25.057] Cloning github.com/TDeV4/nextjs-boilerplate (Branch: main, Commit: ed2db9d)
[16:43:25.609] Cloning completed: 552.422ms
[16:43:28.872] Restored build cache
[16:43:28.929] Running "vercel build"
[16:43:29.394] Vercel CLI 32.0.1
[16:43:29.705] Installing dependencies...
[16:43:30.766] 
[16:43:30.767] up to date in 739ms
[16:43:30.767] 
[16:43:30.767] 136 packages are looking for funding
[16:43:30.767]   run `npm fund` for details
[16:43:30.776] Detected Next.js version: 13.4.8
[16:43:30.779] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[16:43:30.780] Running "npm run build"
[16:43:31.035] 
[16:43:31.035] > nextjs@0.1.0 build
[16:43:31.035] > next build
[16:43:31.035] 
[16:43:31.570] - info Creating an optimized production build...
[16:43:39.495] (node:151) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
[16:43:39.495] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[16:43:40.612] - info Compiled successfully
[16:43:40.614] - info Linting and checking validity of types...
[16:43:42.554] 
[16:43:42.554] Failed to compile.
[16:43:42.554] 
[16:43:42.554] ./components/CoursePlanningTab.js
[16:43:42.555] 130:19  Warning: Assignments to the 'dataToUse' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.556] 
[16:43:42.556] ./components/CreateProfile.js
[16:43:42.556] 221:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'values'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setValues(v => ...)' if you only need 'values' in the 'setValues' call.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.556] 
[16:43:42.556] ./components/CreateReview.js
[16:43:42.556] 58:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getCourseStats'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.556] 
[16:43:42.556] ./components/EditProfile.js
[16:43:42.556] 296:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.userData.coursesTakenID'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setValues' needs the current value of 'props.userData.coursesTakenID', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'props.userData.coursesTakenID' in the reducer.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 303:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.userData.coursesTakingID'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setValues' needs the current value of 'props.userData.coursesTakingID', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'props.userData.coursesTakingID' in the reducer.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 
[16:43:42.557] ./components/EditReview.js
[16:43:42.557] 150:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.reviewData.courseID'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setValues' needs the current value of 'props.reviewData.courseID', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'props.reviewData.courseID' in the reducer.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 179:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'numOfCoursePairings', 'props.reviewData.coursepairingID', and 'props.reviewData.pairingrec'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'setValues' needs the current value of 'props.reviewData.coursepairingID', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'props.reviewData.coursepairingID' in the reducer.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 200:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.reviewData.semester'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setValues' needs the current value of 'props.reviewData.semester', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'props.reviewData.semester' in the reducer.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 
[16:43:42.557] ./components/IndividualCourseInfo.js
[16:43:42.557] 67:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getCourseReviews' and 'getCourseStats'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.557] 134:20  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator  react/jsx-key
[16:43:42.557] 
[16:43:42.557] ./components/ReviewCard.js
[16:43:42.560] 70:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getAnonReviews' and 'getProfileInfo'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[16:43:42.560] 91:7  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[16:43:42.560] 
[16:43:42.560] ./components/TopNavBar.js
[16:43:42.560] 17:15  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[16:43:42.560] 
[16:43:42.560] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
[16:43:42.587] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Has anyone experienced a similar situation and know a fix? Thanks!

I have tried correcting the warning and setting CLI = false in the Vercel environment keys tab but am still getting the failure. Additionally, the site launched successfully one time with the current warnings but has failed on subsequent updates that would not affect any of the warnings that I am being given.

Some information that may be helpful (I assumed it wasn't since it's a compile error rather than a fetching error) but the database is currently on my local machine so Vercel does not have access to pull any data. Would that make a difference if Vercel is unable to grab data? I assumed that would cause errors when viewing the site, not when building it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is failing because your linter is not allowing it to pass. You should be able to run `npm run lint` in your local environment to see what the errors are, fix them locally, and then deploy to Vercel.

These are the lines that make me think that is the issue:

```
[16:43:40.614] - info Linting and checking validity of types...
[16:43:42.554] 
[16:43:42.554] Failed to compile.
```

The rest of the messages are around specific things that aren't right according to your linter. Once you have fixed those, you should be all set.

Comment: That worked! Found the error, thanks!